# How to make asset precompilation work properly with `Rails.env == staging` on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a Heroku instance setup to be a staging server for my application. Up until recently it was working fine however I realised that it also had Rails.env set to equal `:production`. I want it to be `:staging`.

I therefore ran the command

```
heroku config:set RACK_ENV=staging RAILS_ENV=staging --remote staging
```

and also added `config/environments/staging.rb` for the staging environment. That config file mirrored that of the production environment. However, I'm now finding that the asset pipeline is behaving strangely.

If I execute the command:

```
git push staging master
```

then asset compilation doesn't seem to happen at all (in my actual production environment it happens after Heroku has done the slug compilation).

Manually running precompilation on Heroku

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile -a ptw-staging
```

does make the assets compile however, the URLs that are generated return 404 errors. Not only that but the assets which are returned by compilation do not match the ones in the application

For instance, running the compilation command returns:

```
plantheworld-code petenixey$ heroku run rake assets:precompile -a ptw-staging
Running `rake assets:precompile` attached to terminal... up, run.1158
#...
I, [2014-02-05T13:52:28.963871 #2]  INFO -- : Writing /app/public/assets/application-643f7d598dfee123184a638ee696cf15.css
```

as one of the files however in the HTML itself, the application.css file which is included is:

```
<link href="/assets/application-b79916a954fcdab047e735446f1f76a1.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Which is the same file but a different hash on the end.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you set BOTH RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV to staging (can cause hard-to-debug problems).

Also make sure that you've got the `rails_12factor` gem in your staging environment as well as production:

```
gem "rails_12factor", group: [:production, :staging]
```

(you may also need to make sure your pg gem is in both too)